# 2005 suzuki gsxr 600 won't start

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, cranks-wont-run

My bike simply won't start after I replaced the side stand relay, the economy, check all the fuses. It turns over but doesn't start. All my relays work. My fuel pump works. But when I turn the key, the fuel pump does not kick in.
My tachometer does not reset, and the display says CHECK. I tried the dealership thing, still NO CODE displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have fitted the new relay correctly. Check that you did not disturb anything else doing the work. Check the supply and fuses. Check the stand switch for function and adjustment - maybe the relay was not the real or only problem...